# Find optimal/good-enough strategy and AI for the game 'Proximity'?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-theory

'***Proximity***' is a strategy game of territorial domination similar to Othello, Go and Risk.
Two players, uses a 10x12 hex grid. Game invented by *Brian Cable* in 2007.

Seems to be a worthy game for discussing a) optimal algorithm then b) how to build an AI.
Strategies are going to be probabilistic or heuristic-based, due to the randomness factor, and the insane branching factor (20^120).
So it will be kind of hard to compare objectively.
**A compute time limit of 5 seconds max per turn seems reasonable => this rules out all brute-force attempts.** (Play the game's AI on Expert level to get a feel - it does a very good job based on some simple heuristic)

**Game:** [Flash version here](http://www.briancable.com/view.php?id=1), [iPhone version *iProximity* here](http://www.iapplemobileapps.com/iproximity.html) and many copies elsewhere on the web
Rules: [here](http://www.freegamesnews.com/en/?p=1164)

**Object**: to have control of the most armies after all tiles have been placed. You start with an empty hexboard. Each turn you receive a randomly numbered tile (value between 1 and 20 armies) to place on any vacant board space. If this tile is adjacent to any ALLY tiles, it will strengthen each of those tile's defenses +1 (up to a max value of 20). If it is adjacent to any ENEMY tiles, it will take control over them IF its number is higher than the number on the enemy tile.

**Thoughts on strategy:** Here are some initial thoughts; setting the computer AI to Expert will probably teach a lot:

1. minimizing your perimeter seems to be a good strategy, to prevent flips and minimize worst-case damage
2. like in Go, leaving holes inside your formation is lethal, only more so with the hex grid because you can lose armies on up to 6 squares in one move
3. low-numbered tiles are a liability, so place them away from your main territory, near the board edges and scattered. You can also use low-numbered tiles to plug holes in your formation, or make small gains along the perimeter which the opponent will not tend to bother attacking.
4. a triangle formation of three pieces is strong since they mutually reinforce, and also reduce the perimeter
5. Each tile can be flipped at most 6 times, i.e. when its neighbor tiles are occupied. Control of a formation can flow back and forth. Sometimes you lose part of a formation and plug any holes to render that part of the board 'dead' and lock in your territory/ prevent further losses.
6. Low-numbered tiles are obvious-but-low-valued liabilities, but high-numbered tiles can be bigger liabilities if they get flipped (which is harder). One lucky play with a 20-army tile can cause a swing of 200 (from +100 to -100 armies). So tile placement will have both offensive and defensive considerations.

Comment 1,2,4 seem to resemble a minimax strategy where we minimize the maximum expected possible loss (modified by some probabilistic consideration of the value ß the opponent can get from 1..20 i.e. a structure which can only be flipped by a ß=20 tile is 'nearly impregnable'.)
I'm not clear what the implications of comments 3,5,6 are for optimal strategy.
Interested in comments from Go, Chess or Othello players.

(The sequel [ProximityHD for XBox Live, allows 4-player -cooperative or -competitive local multiplayer](http://www.briancable.com/proximityhd/) increases the branching factor since you now have 5 tiles in your hand at any given time, of which you can only play one. Reinforcement of ally tiles is increased to +2 per ally.)

Comment: Did I miss the question?

Comment: I thought the question was clear:
"Strategy and AI: ... discuss a) optimal algorithm then b) how to build an AI."

Comment: @smci discuss is not a question but a wiki

Comment: [@Mike & Lirik, if you quibble the choice of verb]
"Find me the optimal algorithm" (and conjecture why it's optimal)
or "What algorithm do you expect to be optimal?"
Both of those are equivalent to "Discuss the optimal algorithm".
So, does anyone want to venture an answer?

Comment: This game equates closely to Backgammon in that it is essentially the same game with a much larger game space.  The "optimal" algorithm is expecti-max.  I'll answer the second question after I have a chance to implement the game.

Comment: Expectimax is not as good as the *-Minimax variants. I posted a link to my research of *-Minimax below. However, the state space is too large to use any typical techniques (which is why you just don't whip up a generic alpha-beta searcher to play Go).

Comment: In terms of optimality, a full expecti-max roll out is the same as the *-Minimax variants.  You even wrote in Rediscovering *-Minimax Search how expecti-max is the baseline algorithm for perfect information games with chance nodes.  As I read the original post, that was all I thought he was asking for in topic a.  That being said, I understand the practical implications, and very much look forward to replicating your work.  I just think your previous comment is misleading.

Comment: The branching factor -- isn't it a mere 20 * 120?  Looking at the rules, you get a random tile (20), and can then place it in a tile of your choosing (120).

Comment: When I say "not as good" I'm talking about the number of nodes that get searched, i.e. performance.

Comment: In Go, not leaving holes means a sure loss. This is a bloody beginner strategy.

Comment: Conversely, in Proximity, leaving holes which neighbor multiple high-valued tiles is a surefire way to lose, when opponent places a (19 or 20-pt) tile in the middle, you can get a swing of up to 6*19 points in one turn. As such, plugging those gaps (or never creating them in the first place) with even very low-valued tiles is defensively important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general algorithms, I would suggest you to check the research done by the Alberta University AI Games group: http://games.cs.ualberta.ca Many of the algorithms there guarantee to find optimal policies. However, I doubt you're really interested in finding the optimal, aim for the "good enough" unless you want to sell that game in Korea :D

From your description, I have understood the game to be a two-player with full-observability i.e. no hidden units and such and fully deterministic i.e. player's actions outcomes do not require rolling, then you should take a look at the real-time bounded-search minimax derivatives proposed by the U Alberta guys. However, being able to do bound as well the depth of the backups of the value function would perhaps be a nice way to add a "difficulty level" to your game. They have been doing some work - a bit fishy imo - on sampling the search space for improving value function estimates.

About the "strategy" section you describe: in the framework I am mentioning, you will have to encode that knowledge as an evaluation function. Look at the work of Michael Büro and others - also in the U Alberta group - for examples of such knowledge engineering.

Another possibility would be to pose the problem as a Reinforcement Learning problem, where adversary moves are compiled as "afterstates". Look that up on the Barto & Sutton book: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html However the value function for a RL problem resulting from such a compilation might prove a bit difficult to solve optimally - the number of states will blow up like an H-Bomb. However, if you see how to use a factored representation, things can be much easier. And your "strategy" could perhaps be encoded as some shaping function, which would be speeding up the learning process considerably.

EDIT: Damn English prepositions

Comment: miquel, I did say "optimal" but I also said "subject to a time limit of 5 seconds per turn".
So I should have said "good-enough".
I didn't say any memory or CPU limit but let's talk about what's reasonable, say 1MB memory and no disk.

As to whether this game is deterministic, in theory it is if you could handle the branching factor explosion due to all 1..20 possible tile strengths at each turn times ~200 choices of tile placement (worse than Go)
So in practice it is not fully deterministic and you'll need a heuristic - probably one which applies probabilistic weighting (let's assume Minimax)

Comment: I missed the part about time being bounded :-)

The game model is deterministic. But that doesn't mean that the algorithm you use to solve needs to be as well. (In AI research we make a difference about the model and the algorithm). The works I mentioned basically perform Monte Carlo sampling to obtain good estimates by rolling out sequences of plays - I encourage you to take a look into them.

About the heuristic: yes you'll need a good heuristic, but it looks to me that you've already figured out which are the most important features of game states. You just need to combine them.

Comment: The game is not deterministic. It is a stochastic domain due to the random draw of tiles.

Comment: Missed the "randomly drawn tile" bit.

Comment: [...]you're going to need some very aggressive forward pruning techniques. Throw provably best move out the window early and concentrate on building good move ordering.[...]

Such as using a "relaxed" game model which throws aways the uncertainty in the tile drawing :-)

Comment: Right. That's the basic idea behind sampling. It's a valid approach and has been used to create some very good AI for some game types. I personally would adopt a search-centric approach rather than a sampling-centric approach but I would be interested to see how the two compare in this domain.

Answer (score 3):

A former member of the U of A GAMES group here.

That branching factor is insane. Far worse than Go.

Basically, you're hooped.

The problem with this game is that it is not deterministic due to the selection of a random tile. This actually adds another layer of nodes between each existing layer of nodes in the tree. You'll be interested in my [publications on *-Minimax](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~jonathan/Grad/hauk.html) to learn about techniques for searching in stochastic domains.

In order to complete one-ply searches before the end of this century, you're going to need some very aggressive forward pruning techniques. Throw provably best move out the window early and concentrate on building good move ordering.

Comment: Ok, but evidently the builtin AI does a credible job using a very basic heuristic and almost no memory and CPU. So let's start observing how that heuristic behaves (like my attempt in comments 1..6).

Comment: Well I saw the branching factor and figured game over ;) Same reason computer Go is having so many problems. However, what you're saying makes me think there are a huge number of moves which are obviously bad no matter how many ply you search. So I think you should use an iterative deepening approach similar to how gnubackgammon does their forward pruning: search all moves at 1 ply, then sort. Keep the first N moves + M moves within X. Then search all these remaining candidate moves to 2 ply. Lather rinse repeat. This domain may be an interesting followup to my research for *-Minimax.